# row bind tibbles within list

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list where each element contains identifiers and data. The data is stored in a list-column / tibble. How do I reduce the list to one data.frame joining the individual data tibbles by the identifiers and appending the data?

```
a = list(
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp) |> sample_n(5), 
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp) |> sample_n(5)
) 

b = a %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, class = floor(runif(nrow(.x), 0, 2)))) %>%
  map(~ nest(.x, -class))
```

Output of b:

```
✔ [main*]❯ print(b)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [4 × 3]>
2     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     0 <tibble [4 × 3]>
2     1 <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

I want to combine the data columns in b that have the same identifier `class`.

** So, the expected output is:**

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [5 × 3]>
2     0 <tibble [5 × 3]>
```

Using `b |> reduce(inner_join, by = "class")` flattens the list to one tibble, but now the data columns are columns of the new tibble, and not combined to one column.

EDIT:
Note that in my use case `b` has more than two lists and I'd like the code to be general enough to not have to know beforehand how many lists there are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `reduce` step, we may need to bind the rows (Updated after addressing the comments from OP)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
 b %>% 
   reduce(inner_join, by = "class") %>% 
   transmute(class, data = pmap(across(starts_with('data')), bind_rows))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data             
  <dbl> <list>           
1     0 <tibble [11 × 3]>
2     1 <tibble [9 × 3]>
```

---

Or another option is `powerjoin` with `conflict` as a function

```
b %>% 
  reduce(power_inner_join, by = "class", 
      conflict = \(x, y) map2(x, y, bind_rows))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data             
  <dbl> <list>           
1     0 <tibble [11 × 3]>
2     1 <tibble [9 × 3]>
```

---

The input `b` was

```
> b
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     0 <tibble [3 × 3]>
2     1 <tibble [2 × 3]>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [3 × 3]>
2     0 <tibble [2 × 3]>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [3 × 3]>
2     0 <tibble [2 × 3]>

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [1 × 3]>
2     0 <tibble [4 × 3]>
```

Comment: Thanks! Using map within mutate/transmute is something I always forget. But this gets awkward with more than 2 lists and impossible when I don't know exactly how many lists there are and what the names coming from inner_join will be. Is there a more general way? I realize that wasn't clear from my question, so I'll edit it.